# What's the font that Lawson, Inc. (Japanese convenience store) used?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Searching for the font that Lawson, Inc. (the Japanese convenience store) used for their logo (the Latin alphabet one). I've tried to identify the font using services like What the font! and What Font Is, there's some fonts that are similar to it, but no luck on finding the exact font they used. So anyone has any idea as to what font they are using?[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Do you mean the Latin alphabet font, or the Japanese one? Please [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/125642/edit) your question to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a custom design based on [Wild West Font](https://www.ffonts.net/WildWest-Normal.font.download#)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be [Winner Wide Medium](https://www.fonts.com/font/sportsfonts/winner/wide-medium) or [Winner Wide Bold](https://www.fonts.com/font/sportsfonts/winner/wide-bold) with a couple of *really terrible type changes* to kerning and the rounded slab serif style (thick, block-like serifs). It also looks like they transformed the original typeface to a geometric font design.

I have attached a quick and rough simulation: original vs. Winner Wide font [image: font-WinnerWide-quick-simulation]